# Извлечение математического выражения из строки (Java)

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно посчитать  математическое выражение из строки, например:

```
    evaluate((1 + 38) * 4.5 - 1 / 2);


    public String evaluate(String statement){
//todo??
    return;
    }
```

Comment: Задавайте конкретный вопрос, если что-то существует, то мы должны об этом знать прежде чем рассматривать ваш вопрос.

Comment: Куда извлечь? Из этой строки ничего извлекать не надо, она вся математическое выражение.

Answer (score 2):

```
public  double calc(String input){
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    return (Double)engine.eval(input);
}

String s = "((1 + 38) * 4.5 - 1 / 2)";

System.out.println(calc(s));
```

Comment: с возвращаемым string как можно сделать?

Comment: public String calc(String input)  {
  int result = 0;
  ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
  ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
  return engine.eval(input).toString();
 }

Answer (score 1):

Для вычисления парсите строку.Используйте метод обратной польской записи, посмотреть про алгоритм можно здесь http://www.interface.ru/home.asp?artid=1492